# My React Native android app is not running (Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED)

Tags: android, react-native

I am unable to run react native android app after update of android gradle to
"classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'" and added "kotlin_version='1.6.0'".

**My android --> build.gradle **

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
        kotlin_version='1.6.0' //add This change version with your installed kotlin version
    }
```

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" //add This

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

** Facing Error  **

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
608 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 606 up-to-date
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libfbjni.so'
```

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hYyF.png)

I added kotlin version and change gradle to "3.6.3" , I expected that it will run after added kotlin and gradle version changes but i am unable to open app.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the allprojects area of your android/buld.gradle file.

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
```